# My html code isn't calling the javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm using a submit button for a form and the javascript should tell me if any field is empty.. But despite using the onclick attribute , nothing's happening.. There's ablock of PHP code which refuses to store the data. I'm a beginner to PHP and Javascript so any ideas?

```
<script language="javascript">
   function valid()
   {
       var a=document.form2.i1.value;
       var b=document.form2.pas.value;
       var c=document.form2.pas1.value;
       var d=document.form2.n1.value;
       var e=document.form2.a1.value;
       var f=document.form2.r1.value;
       var g=document.form2.pin1.value;
       var h=document.form2.phno1.value;
       var i=document.form2.u1.value;
       var j=document.form2.email1.value;


       if(a!="y")
       {
           alert("Please accept the terms and conditions before registering.");
           return false;
       }
       else if(d=="")
       {
           alert("Name required.");
           return false;
       }
       else if(e=="")
       {
           alert("Age required.");
           return false;
       }
       else if(e<18)
       {
           alert("You have to be atleast 18 to register.");
           return false;
       }
       else if(f="")
       {
           alert("Gender required.");
           return false;
       }
       else if(g=="" || isNan(g))
       {
           alert("Valid pincode required.");
           return false;
       }
       else if(h==""|| isNan(h))
       {
           alert("Valid phone number required.");
           return false;
       }
       else if(i=="")
       {
           alert("Username required.");
           return false;
       }
       else if(j=="")
       {
           alert("Email required.");
           return false;
       }
       else if(b=="" || c=="")
       {
           alert("Password required.");
           return false;
       }
       else if(b!=c)
       {
           alert("Please make sure the passwords are identical.");
           return false;
       }
       return true;

   }

   </script>
```

This is the statement I used to call it:

```
<div id="apDiv3"><input name="reg1" type="submit" id="login-submit" value="Register" onclick="return valid()"/></div>
```

This is the PHP code I used to create the form:

```
 <?php
              if(isset($_POST['reg1']))
              {
                  $name=$_POST['n1'];
                  $age=$_POST['a1'];
                  $gen=$_POST['r1'];
                  $phno=$_POST['phno1'];
                  $email=$_POST['email1'];
                  $pin=$_POST['pin1'];
                  $user=$_POST['u1'];
                  $pas=$_POST['pass'];
                  $pas1=$_POST['pass1'];
                  $i=$_POST['i1'];


                      $connection=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$connection) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_error($connection));
}
                     $db_select = mysqli_select_db($connection, "vinay");
if (!$db_select) {
    die("Database selection failed: " . mysqli_error($db_select));
}
                      $q="insert into reg values('0','$name','$age','$gen','$phno','$email','$pin','$user','$pas')";
                      mysqli_query($q) or die(mysqli_error($q));
                      if(mysqli_affected_rows()>0)
                      {
                header("location:index.php");

                      }




                  }
                 ?>
```

Comment: Try changing `<script language="javascript">` to `<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: When you use an `<input>` node with `type="submit"`, that's exactly what that button will do: submit a form.

Comment: Give meaningful names to your variables. `abcdefg` will drive you mad soon, if they already didn't.

Comment: can I suggest u to use jquery? It will help a lot...

Comment: If you want to check a form for empty input fields before the form submits, look up onsubmit="return myFunction()"

Comment: If you have a form, make it's `method="post"`, otherwise, make your input type to `type="button"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to use JavaScript when HTML5 already has attributes for this purpose. Use the `pattern` and the `required` attributes.
For reference see: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_attributes.asp